# Issues with Bash and NPM paths

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

(bash newbie alert)

I'm having a hell of a time getting my dev machine up and running post clean install of 10.10.

I first attempted to install everything via homebrew. After installing Yeoman I was still getting "Yo" command not found errors.  I followed these instructions http://d.pr/1hjAi on the Yeoman FAQ however I'm still getting the errors.  I then realized I didn't have a .bash_profile, .bashrc or a .profile file in my home directory. I've tried adding just about every path variable I've found on line and nothing seems to fix it.  On top of that, adding a path to any of the files mentioned above doesn't seem to update the path.

echo $PATH gives me
/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin/npm:/bin:/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Any help would be great.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $SHELL` and `ls /usr/local/share/npm/bin`?

Comment: echo $Shell produces /bin/bash and ls: /usr/local/share/npm/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: Then it seems NPM isn't correctly installed. Did you see any errors during the installation?

Comment: I originally installed using homebrew, I did get some errors so I uninstalled then installed using the installer from the node website

Comment: The installer claims its installed at  /usr/local/bin/node, is that the default or perhaps its getting the location from a variable on my machine?

Comment: Can you add `/usr/local/bin/node` to your path and then in a shell with this new path, try it again?

Comment: Thanks,   I added it and I'm still getting yo: command not found

Comment: After installing bower with npm install -g bower, I'm also getting a bower:command not found